# Column dimension tabu

Tags: tables

Instead have two columns of the same dimension I want that the first one smaller while the other one that depends on the content. I'm just writing a table there in the first column I put the name of some equations (for each row) and in the other column the equation.
I tried with

```
\begin{tabu} { | X[l]{0.1/textwith} | X[c] |}
 \hline
 item 11 & item 12 \\
 \hline
 item 21  & item 22   \\
\hline
\end{tabu}
```

but give me the error

> Package array error: illegal pream-token

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input `{0.1/textwith}` is illegal. In general, if you want to specify a fraction of the text width, the syntax would be `0.1\textwidth`. Anyhow, that's out of place in that context.

I also added a final `\strut` because `tabu` doesn't. I'd stay at arm's length from the package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabu} { | X[0.1,l]<{\unskip\strut} | X[c] |}
 \hline
 item 11 & item 12 \\
 \hline
 item 21  & item 22   \\
\hline
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

The fraction of `\linewidth` should be specified in the optional argument to `X`.

[image]